# YouTrack windows service starts then stops

Tags: youtrack

I have installed YouTrack as a windows service, on the same box as TeamCity. TeamCity works fine, but the YouTrack windows service stops as soon as it is started.

Can anyone point me towards log files for youTrack, or has anyone expreienced this before? I have been unable to find anything on google.

I set up YouTrack using this article:
http://blog.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-youtrack-in-iis-7/

though I have not even got to the IIS part. I have tried both the stable release and the latest EAP build.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the port you've chosen is already used by some other application, check YouTrack logs for more details, they are located under the installation directory, for example:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\YouTrack\logs
```

Note that if you run TeamCity on the same machine, at least one more port (except the default HTTP port) could conflict, edit `conf\server.xml`:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

TeamCity Tomcat is most likely using the same shutdown port, so you need to change it. Change other conflicting ports if you find them reported in the logs.